# How to open browser from Xamarin forms for local html content

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, webbrowser-control

I know by using

`Device.OpenUri(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));`

can open the url in external web browser. I have hard coded html contents that should be opened in external web browser.

I hope the creation of uri for local contents will be able to open it in browser.

**Note: I cant use Webview due to some limitation.**

Any idea from anyone?

Answer (score 1):

If you save the html as a file, you can use:

```
Device.OpenUri(new Uri("file://path/to/file/here.html"))
```

You should be able to see your local html in the browser.

Comment: This should work. Be aware, however, that you may need to treat files differently on different platforms. See here for more info: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/files/

Comment: i'm pretty new to xamarin, where should we give this code(which file), app.xaml.cs or MainPage.xaml.cs